# Handle Concurrency with transaction (Spring Data JPA) with respect to user

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, spring-data-jpa

I have 10 concurrent request for same user which is going to my upsert service . Where i have secnario such that if there is already available it will update or else will create.

Here when requests came all will find that there is no any data present and went to create. But i want this can be handled with respect to particular user . I don't want synchronised block or so because it will restrict all the request . i want something like lock for particular user.

Suggest some better approach.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking

Comment: this is not something i am looking at. @JBNizet. Please suggest something better.

Comment: Why? That's the only reliable, clusterable way to do what you want (other than using the serializable isolation level, or to use an update query to modify your entity).

Comment: when i use isolation level as SERIALIZABLE  it is giving LockAcquisitionException. I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize your code by the value of `user.id` for example. In this case, you don't block all requests, you block only requests on the same `id`.

Look at this library [XSync](https://github.com/antkorwin/xsync) (to make synchronization by the value of object).

I hope it helps.

Comment: I hope this will work. I will try it and will update you soon. Thanks